# Doing tasks in a random order

Tags: python, random

I have the following function for assigning points to a caracters stats.:

```
def randstat(level):
    from random import randint
    points = randint(10,max(20,5*level))

    agility=randint(0,points)
    points -= agility

    stamina=randint(0,points)
    points -=stamina

    strength=randint(0,points)
    points -=strength

    vitality=randint(0,points)
    points -=vitality

    inteligence=randint(0,points)
    points -= inteligence
```

It works as i should expect, however as you go down the list of stats, there are less points to distrubute, so stats like `inteligence` or `vitality` get far less points than `agility` or `stamina`. How could I assign points to each of these stats in a random order, Ie, it dosn't always assign `agility` first then `inteligence` last?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go about this in the opposite way - rather than trying to fill each stat with a random number, choose which stat to increment at random and repeat.

This will result in more 'even' stats and make situations where the character has one stat at max points and the rest at zero far less common.

```
def randstat(level):
    points = randint(10,max(20,5*level))

    # set all our minimums to zero
    stats = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    for i in range(points):
        stat = randint(0, len(stats)-1); # pick a random stat to increment
        stats[stat] = stats[stat] + 1

    # extract the stats back out of our array
    agility = stats[0]
    stamina = stats[1]
    strength = stats[2]
    vitality = stats[3]
    intelligence = stats[4]
```

Comment: I have tried your code, it suits me. execpt when i add all the stats up i end up with one less point than i started with. any idea why this is?

Comment: Yeah, it should be `range(points)` as `range(1,points)` loops from `1` to `points-1`.  I'll fix it up

Answer (score 1):

That's an easy one!  ;-)
I think this way the code will be much shorter and clear. I hope you find it useful.

```
def randstat(level):
    from random import randint
    from random import shuffle
    points = randint(10,max(20,5*level))

    # Values of stats
    sValues = []

    # Loop as many times as stats
    for i in range(5):
        sValues.append(randint(0,points))
        points -= sValues[-1]

    # Reorder randomly the values of stats
    shuffle(sValues)
    # and assign them to the final variables
    agility, stamina, strength, vitality, intelligence = sValues
```